# JS WebdriverIO how to click checkbox

Tags: checkbox

How to click checkbox:

```
<div class="form-row in-focus-or-has-value">
            <input type="checkbox" id="agree_terms_conditions_agree">
            <label for="agree_terms_conditions_agree">
                I agree with <a href="/terms">Terms</a> and <a href="/policy">Policy</a>
            </label>
        </div>
```

tried like this:

```
const idAgreeTermsConditionsAgree = await $('#agree_terms_conditions_agree')
idAgreeTermsConditionsAgree.checked = true;
await idAgreeTermsConditionsAgree.click()

$('label[for="agree_terms_conditions_agree"]').click()
```

presses `<a href="/terms">`
Can't click on checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const idAgreeTermsConditionsAgree = await $("label[for=\'agree_terms_conditions_agree\']")
await idAgreeTermsConditionsAgree.click({ x: -10 })
```